# How can I speed up the loading of models in Keras and Tensorflow?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras, django-rest-framework

Let's assume that I have a large amount of trained keras models and I have to sometimes load them and make predictions. I need to load every model and predict data in the fastest possible way. I think that the fastest solution is to store them in the memory however I guess that it is not good way because soon ot later the RAM will overflow? So at this point I achieve the highest performance with something like this.

```
K.clear_session()
random_model = load_model('path/to/' + str(random_model))
results = random_model(final_input_row)
```

In addition I have five models which I use almost all the time and in this case the performance is even more important. I load them during starting the server and I have a constant access to them.

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

with graph.as_default():

    constant_model = load_model(
            'path/to/constant_model')
```

prediction:

```
with graph.as_default():
    results = constant_model(final_input_row)
```

The problem is that during `K.clear_session()` which I execute during loading `random_models` I lost them from the memory. Without `K.clear_session()` loading of `random_models` last too long. Do you have any ideas how can I solve this? I can even use completely different methods.

**UPDATE**

I try to do something like this:

```
class LoadModel:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.sess  = tf.Session(config=config)
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        K.set_session(self.sess)
        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.model = load_model(self.path)

    def do_predictions(self, x):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            return self.model.predict(x)
```

And then when I execute:

```
random_model = LoadModel('./path/to/random_model.h5')
results = random_model.do_predictions(final_input_row)
```

It takes something about 3 seconds to predict data. In the case of `random_models` when I have a lot of models it is acceptable. However in the case of `constant_models` when I have five of them and I need to have constant access to them it lasts too long. Until now, I did it in such a way that I was loading the model during starting the Django server and I stored this in the memory and then I could just run `results = constant_model.do_predictions(final_input_row)` and it was very fast. It works okay until I run `random_models`, after that in every request I get

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Tensor lstm_14_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
[24/Jun/2019 10:11:00] "POST /request/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17326
[24/Jun/2019 10:11:02] "GET /model/ HTTP/1.1" 201 471
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession._Callable.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.BaseSession._Callable object at 0x130069908>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1455, in __del__
    self._session._session, self._handle, status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No such callable handle: 140576717540032
[24/Jun/2019 10:11:02] "GET /model/ HTTP/1.1" 201 471
[24/Jun/2019 10:11:07] "GET /model/ HTTP/1.1" 201 471
```

Obviously it works properly if I run `constant_model = LoadModel('./path/to/constant_model.h5')` before every `results = constant_model.do_predictions(final_input_row)` however as I have mentioned it is too slow. Any ideas how to solve this?

**UPDATE2**

I try in this way

```
session  = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)

class LoadModel:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.model = load_model(self.path)

    def do_predictions(self, x):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            return self.model.predict(x)
```

but still I get `TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(1, 128), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`

**SOLUTION**
Below is my working solution. If anyone knows an even more efficient way of loading the model that meets the requirements described above, I will be grateful for the message.

```
class LoadModel:

    def __init__(self, model_path):
        with K.get_session().graph.as_default():
            self.model = load_model(model_path)
            self.model._make_predict_function()
            self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    def predict_data(self, data):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            output = self.model.predict(data)
            return output
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are using all the models all the time, it will be good to keep them in memory so that you are not loading and predicting every time you make a request. For example, you should define a class that loads a model and keep different instances of this class for different models. This is not a tested code, so you may have to make some changes.

```
# if you are using GPU
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

class LoadModel:
    def __init__(self, path_to_model):
        self.path  = path
        self.sess  = tf.Session(config=config)
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        K.set_session(self.sess) 
        self.model = self.load()

    def load(self):
        with graph.as_default():
            model = load_model(self.path)
        return model

    def do_predictions(self, x):
        return self.model.predict(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help however it doesn't solve my problem. I updated my question with the current source code. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: But it will be slow only on the first run as it have to compile the first time. Any subsequent call should be in real time

Comment: But the model is loaded every time when the data is predicting so it doesn't change anything whether I run model the first time or multiple times. Maybe it is possible to change this?

Comment: The network should load only once when you intitialize an instance of the class.

Comment: You shouldn't initialize a new instance on every call. Reuse the instance that you made earlier for the subsequent calls

Comment: I initialize a new instance of the network during starting the sever. Let's call this `instance1`. Everything works properly until I initialize new class of another network `instance2`. Then `instance2` is working properly however when I want to predict data using `instance1` I get `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Tensor lstm_14_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph` Do you have any idea what may be causing this error?

Comment: Maybe this line `K.set_session(self.sess)`

Comment: I updated the question. Removing `K.set_session(self.sess)` doesn't change anything. Any other ideas?